# How to install win32com module in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pywin32

I have installed both `virtualenv` and `pywin32` on my Windows 7 64-bit laptop, and each of them seems to work, but not with each other.

More specifically, if a virtualenv is active, then running `import win32com.client` in a python interactive shell fails with `No module named win32com.client`.  The same expression succeeds, however, if no virtualenv is active.

When I try to install `pywin32` with `pip` (which is how I normally install modules when a virtualenv is active), I get the error:

```
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32
No distributions at all found for pywin32
```

...even though `pywin32` is one of the modules listed in the output of

```
pip search pywin32
```

Therefore, to install `pywin32` *at all* I had to install it using an *.exe installer downloaded from SourceForge.

Is there any way to install `pywin32` within a virtualenv?

Comment: `pip install pypiwin32` might work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use pywin32 with a virtualenv without having to include the host environment's site-packages folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830304/how-can-i-use-pywin32-with-a-virtualenv-without-having-to-include-the-host-envir)

Answer (score 35):

#### UPDATE 2016

There is now a version of pywin32 on PyPI that can be installed with pip. It is called `pypiwin32`, and it installs the package using the binary `wheel` format.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

That will work in a virtualenv, or with tox, etc.

---

Below this line is my previous old answer. That is now outdated information.

> OLD ANSWER - OUTDATED. Modern versions of virtualenv default to --no-site-packages. That means that not having access to global site-packages is now the default behavior.
>  
>  Sadly, (as of July 2014) you can not pip install pywin32 in to your virtualenv. ([here's the bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/669/))
>  
>  If you want to get pywin32 running inside a virtualenv, activate the virtualenv and use easy_install and the pywin32 installer exe file. For example
>  
>      easy_install "C:\Path\To\Downloads\pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe"

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639947/how-do-you-install-pywin32-from-a-binary-file-in-tox-on-windows)

Comment: I'm getting ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (Python 3.5.2 32bit virtualenv on Win2012R2)

Comment: Not working. 
`No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

1. [Download directly](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)
2. Enable your virtualenv
3. `pip install --no-index --find-links:/local/dir/ SomePackage`

Check out #8 on [pip-installer.org](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html) (sorry no permalink)/

Comment: For those on Anaconda: just do `conda install pywin32`

Answer (score 2):

Create a virtualenv and activate it:

`cd c:\Users\ernesto.luzon
virtualenv --no-site-packages py351env
py351env\Scripts\activate`

From here, you have two options:

1. Download pywin32 from sourceforge project:
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
2. Download pywin32 from unofficial (but very helpful) binary site:
   http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

Make sure you download the correct version for the Python Interpreter installed in your environment, otherwise you will encounter [ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434283/dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application/35291566#35291566) later.

If you downloaded from sourceforge, install it using easy_install:

`(py351env) C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\Downloads>easy_install pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.5.exe`

If you downloaded from gohlke, install it using pip:

`(py351env) C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\Downloads>pip install pywin32-220-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`

In case you encounter [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238403/import-win32api-error-in-python-2-6) error later on, you need these additional steps:

Run the post install script:

`(py351env) C:\Users\ernesto.luzon>python py351env\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
Copied pythoncom35.dll to C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\py351env\pythoncom35.dll
Copied pywintypes35.dll to C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\py351env\pywintypes35.dll
....`

Notice where it copied the 'pythoncom35.dll' and 'pywintypes35.dll' files. You need to move these files to the folder:
`C:\Users\ernesto.luzon\py351env\Lib\site-packages\win32`