# How to type into cmd using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, converters

I have a program here that I would like to convert to 2.7. This code works well in Python 3.x, however, for my needs it must be 2.7. Could someone 'convert' this to python 2.7 for me? I have heard of a 3to2.py tool but I do know how to get/use it. Anyway, here is the code I have for 3.3.

```
def compiler(program):
    import os, win32com.client, time
    os.startfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
    time.sleep(2)
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shell.AppActivate('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe')
    setup(program)
    shell.SendKeys("py MyCompiling.py.setup("+program+") py2exe\n")

def setup(program):
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe
    setup(console=[program + ".py"])

compiler('test1')
```

EDIT: When I try to run I get

```
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

Do I have to install this module seperately? If so, could someone please post the link.

Comment: What exactly fails under python2.7?  At a quick glance, I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work unless something in `win32com.client` fails under python2.7 ...

Comment: win32com.client works fine in 2.7 i think its the `setup(program)`

Comment: This code contains *NO* Python3-isms AFAICS. If you are having trouble running it under Python 2.7, it's probably because of missing modules (such as win32com, which [appears to be a separately-installable module.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913607/how-to-install-win32com-module-in-a-virtualenv)). Be aware that modules in 3.x and 2.7 are entirely separate: installing a module in 3.x won't make it available in 2.7, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must install the library separately. In fact, if you visit the [SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/), you will see that there is an entirely different binary available for 2.7. You will want [pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe/download) if you are using 32-bit Python or [pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win-amd64-py2.7.exe/download) if you are using 64-bit Python.

You can install it via the GUI interface (which comes up when you try to execute the file), or you can call easy_install on it (if you have setuptools or distribute installed) at the command line:

```
C:\> C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe
```

Using easy_install is the only way if you want to install the library in a virtual environment created with [virutalenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).