# How do you install pywin32 from a binary file in tox on Windows?

Tags: python, testing, pywin32, tox

My application depends on pywin32 which I have installed in my system environment via Windows binary file. How do you install a module like pywin32 from a binary file in tox on Windows?

Answer (score 10):

There is now a version of pywin32 on PyPI that can be installed with pip. It is called `pypiwin32`, and it installs the package using the binary `wheel` format.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Or, in `tox.ini`

```
[testenv]
deps = pypiwin32
```