# How to install pywin32 in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pywin32

Errors that I am getting:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

The python version installed is: `Python 3.7.6`

Is there any workaround or manual process to install the package in anaconda?

Comment: Hi, welcome at Stackoverflow! Could you explain what you tried to run into these errors?

Comment: @matheburg: am simply trying to install the package in anaconda via pip. Be it pypiwin32 or pywin32, neither works. Wondering if python have stopped supporting this package? And what alternates are out there for it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try using [pypiwin32](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/) instead of pywin32.

or

If you want to use pywin32 you can check this [How do you install pywin32 from a binary file in tox on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639947/how-do-you-install-pywin32-from-a-binary-file-in-tox-on-windows)