# How to handle windows authentication popup using selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Authentication window snap]

Already tried following methods,

1) https://username:password@sitename.com

My username contains '\' thats why it is giving problem.

2) switch to alert method
In this I am getting 'No alert' Exception

Please help in these cases/ Suggest any other method to handle windows authentication with python...

Comment: You should try to url encode the back slash. Otherwise, your site seems to not want you to automate or Web scrape  against it

Comment: Does any of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium?lq=1 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java ?

Comment: By using encode value of '\', it's working....

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

Install [win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913607/how-to-install-win32com-module-in-a-virtualenv) and then try the below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import win32com.client

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('url')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
shell.Sendkeys("username")  
shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
shell.Sendkeys("password") 
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: just watch out that you don't click anywhere else in Windows, because the text will be sent wherever you have your cursor!