# pyodbc module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, pyodbc

I am facing a situation where modules like `pyodbc` which used to work earlier (3 weeks back) are not working anymore in my laptop. I am repeatedly getting `Module not found` error.

To resolve it by myself, I have gone through similar articles in stack overflow and implemented some suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085191/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyodbc-when-importing-pyodbc-into-py-scri). Yet the issue still persists. My machine `(Windows 10)` has only one python version `(python v3.7.2)`, and I have never created any `virtualenv`.

```
C:\Users\Kris\eclipse-workspace\SQLPyODBC>conntest.py --serverName "IDEA-PC\SQLEXPRESS" --name "SampleStore" --trustedConn "yes"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kris\eclipse-workspace\SQLPyODBC\conntest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

The referenced package is available under `C:\Users\Kris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` directory. Also the path of python interpreter in eclipse IDE (PyDev) is pointing to correct python executable path.

Just to test, I have downloaded `pymssql` module, and guess what... it is also showing the same error message. I have uninstalled and re-installed packages. No solution.

Comment: Sounds like it cannot find it, period. Is the Python Path set at an IDE level? Is their a project level path that's overwriting it perhaps? Try running python from command line and try importing the modules there to verify they are installed.

Comment: @GreenGodot Python path of IDE and project are pointing to same location. I was able to successfully import pyodbc in IDLE environment (command line).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Anaconda install using following code,

```
conda install -c anaconda pyodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

Before importing pyodbc in python, you should install the module by using pip directly from cmd.

```
pip install pyodbc
```

if that does not work, try using pip to uninstall and install it again after a restart (Or kill all python related tasks). Hope it works

Comment: I have installed the module in question using pip before referring it in my source code. Also as described in the question, I have uninstalled and re-installed the package.