# pip install pyodbc is not working on python

Tags: python, pip

I installed Python on my Windows 10 computer

when I try to run my python code

I get error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

I checked multiple questions here and the solution is to pip pyodbc

I tried that

```
pip install pyodbc
```

but i get error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[image]

I checked similar propblems here and it seems that **pip** is not installed.

I unistalled and reinstalled python from **python.org** and still same issue!

any solution?

**Edit**

I did as suggested to try from command prompt

but still same error

[image]

I installed Python with ticking the option to include environment variables option.

**Edit 2 :**

I think the problem was that I was trying to install from witthin python.

I misunderstood the answers, I have to run pip as an application outside of python. to allocate pop.exe and then do pip install.

Comment: You have to run `pip install pyobdc` in the command prompt. That's the Python shell, and that's invalid Python code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: @asmgx your confusion is understandable.  Too many into to Python tutorials don't take the time to explain home paths and interpreters work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you run pip from a shell, not from a Python interactive session.

```
C:\PATHTOPYTHON\python.exe pip install <<SOMEPACKAGE>>
```

See the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817447/how-to-run-pip-commands-from-cmd), if you want to install from within a Python interactive session.

Comment: I did as suggested to try from command prompt

but still same error

Comment: python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program Files\Python39\pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @asmgx if you start a cmd.exe shell, and type "where python," what comes up?

Answer (score 4):

You would run pip from a shell, not from the IDLE. However, pyodbc requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver. More information about installing the pyodbc module can be seen in this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-2017). This Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667554/12602208) can also help.

Comment: I did as suggested to try from command prompt

but still same error

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to install the package from python interpreter (IDLE) which is wrong. You should only import package from IDLE terminal (python session) which IDLE has access to.

Try this link to install the package --> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

Comment: I did as suggested to try from command prompt

but still same error