# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc' even though pyodbc is installed

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyodbc, modulenotfounderror

I have installed pyodbc inside my virtual environment(venv). However when I try to import this package it throws *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'*.[image]

Below is the screenshot of what happen when I run `pip install pyodbc`

[image]

also, I can see pyodbc is installed on venv with the output of pip freeze. Please help me resolve this issue so that I can use pyodbc module in my virtual environment.

Comment: Does the first answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085191/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyodbc-when-importing-pyodbc-into-py-scri?rq=1 help solve the issue?

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer, No it didn't work. I got same message - Requirement already satisfied

Comment: Have you tried trying it again on a fresh install of python?

Comment: I created a new virtual environment and it worked