# Anaconda 3 not installing pyodbc v5

Tags: python, anaconda, pyodbc, miniconda

I have installed Anaconda 3 which includes Python 3.9.16. When I install pyodbc in miniconda it is only version 4. I read it needs to be version 5 if Python is above 3.7. When I run my Python script it I get the message
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'` even though it is installed.

Is this because pyodbc is version 4 and should be version 5 or could it be another reason? I've tried all of the different flavours of installing pyodbc via Conda but I still get this error. I do also have Python 3.11 installed manually. Could there be a conflict?

Comment: Refer to this [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085191/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyodbc-when-importing-pyodbc-into-py-scri). It worked for me.

Comment: The latest version of pyodbc is 4.0.35. pyodbc 5 does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I installed Python 3.9 separately to the Anaconda install and I had to install pyodbc using the pip command and it worked. I assumed Anaconda used a different install of Python and would require a conda install.